# Any relation between the size of maximum independent set and the chromatic number on graph of bounded degree?

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, graph-colouring

Consider an connected undirected graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and maximum degree $\Delta$. Assume $G$ contains a maximum independent set of size $k$. Is there any relation between the chromatic number $\chi(G)$ and $k$? Say of the form $\chi(G)\le f(\Delta)\frac{n}{k}$ for some function $f$?

Comment: What is $d$?  I'm assuming you want this function $f(d)$ to be independent of $\Delta$?  If so, how can $\Delta$ help us?  If not, do you want something better than the trivial bound of $\Delta+1$?

Comment: Sorry, f($\Delta$) indeed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obviously if $f(\Delta)=2\Delta$ then the bound holds.  However, I doubt this is what you meant.  Perhaps you meant $\chi(G) \leq f(\frac n k)$, in which case the answer is *no*, there is no such function.

Let $\alpha$ be the size of a maximum independent set in $G$.  Then it is easy to see that the fractional chromatic number satisfies the bound $\chi_f(G)\geq \frac n \alpha$.  One such example is the Kneser graph $K_{kb:b}$ for fixed integers $k$ and $b$.  This graph has fractional chromatic number $k = \frac n\alpha$, and chromatic number $(k-2)b+2$.  So for fixed $k$ and large $b$ the answer is no.

(See Section 3.1 of my thesis for more details. http://www.columbia.edu/~ak3074/papers/phdthesis-compact.pdf)

Comment: The file is damaged and could not be repaired....

Comment: link does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

χ(G) + α(G) <= n+1
where n is the number of vertices of the graph.

Proof by Induction:
Notice that a single vertex has χ(G) + α(G) = 2.
Add each vertex one by one.
Notice that by adding a single vertex you can only increase them by one. By doing this, we convert G into G*.
Say the new vertex v is connected to vertices 1 through r of our previous G and not connected to the vertices r+1 through n.
For the inequality to be disturbed according to our induction hypothesis both have to be increased at one point

For χ(G) to increase, the 1 through r vertices, v is connected to needs r colours in any proper colouring of G. Thus |r| >= χ(G).
Also the maximum independent set that v must be part of has to be contained in G - r. Therefore 
|G - r| >= α(G)
Adding the two inequalities gets you
|G| = n >= χ(G) + α(G)

Now both increase, showing that n+2>=χ(G*) + α(G*)
Thus χ(G*) + α(G*) <= |G*| + 1
QED
The bound is tight for complete graphs and null graphs.

Comment: I think that your statement has an obvious (non-inductive) proof. Take a maximal independent set $S$ in your graph, color all the vertices of $S$ with color 1, and all the remaining vertices of $G$ with pairwise distinct colors. You obtain a coloring of $G$ with $n-\alpha(G)+1$ colors, so $\chi(G)+\alpha(G)\leq n+1$.